# How do I use javascript in codenameone without an open browser page

Tags: codenameone

I will like to use some javascript libraries in Codenameone. My current understanding is that I have to use a BrowserComponent and establish a javascript context. My problem is that when I use the BrowserComponent, I cannot hide it or stop it from opening. My use case does not require a web page to be open.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add the `BrowserComponent` to any hierarchy in order to use the JavaScript engine within. So yes you need a `BrowserComponent` but you don't need to put it anywhere.